Density ratio estimation based classification
Consider the classification problem $p(y \mid x)$ where $y$ is the label and $x$ is the feature vector, e.g. an image. Normally, we would fit, e.g. a convolutional network, and predict $y$ given $x$. Yesterday it came to my mind that, by Bayes rule, $\log p(y \mid x) = \log p(y) + \color{blue}{\log \frac{p(x \mid y)}{p(x)}}$. Since $\log p(y)$ can be trivially estimated from the dataset, finding the log density ratio (colored blue) will be equivalent to finding the classifier $p(y \mid x)$. By density ratio trick (Sugiyama et al., 2012; Dhuliawala et al., 2023), the log density ratio can be found by fitting a family of classifiers $T_y(x)$ (one may also opt to fit one amortized classifier) that distinguish samples of $p(x \mid y)$ from samples of $p(x)$. $T_y(x)$ is optimized when $\mathbb E_{p(x \mid y)}[\log \sigma(T_y(x))] + \mathbb E_{p(x)}[\log (1-\sigma(T_y(x)))]$ is maximized, where $\sigma(\cdot)$ is the sigmoid function. It then follows that $\log p(y \mid x) = \log p(y) + T_y(x)$. One advantage might be that calibration to label shift is trivial.
Is such method ever used in practice? I'd really appreciate it if anyone could point me to related literature. Thank you so much!

It is unclear to me, what you want to do? What do you mean by "distinguish samples of p(x∣y)
from samples of p(x)
" ?
